# Is it possible to dismiss the on-screen keyboard for a mobile website using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, mobile, mobile-website

I don't actually want to do this; I'm just curious if it's *possible*. Apparently [there are some hacky ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593139/ipad-web-app-detect-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript-in-safari) to check whether an on-screen keyboard is visible; however, I'm wondering if you can actually *dismiss* the keyboard using JavaScript.

That is, if you have a form that the user is filling out, and they enter an input field so the keyboard appears, is there any way to make it **disappear**?

Comment: Duplicate: [Hide keyboard in iPhone Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890216/hide-keyboard-in-iphone-safari-webapp)