# Hide iPhone's keyboard using Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone

Does anyone know how to **hide** iPhone's keyboard in Safari after user touch button "Go" instead of "Done"?

I need solution for Javascript and HTML5.

Comment: Try using `focus()` on an element that doesn't accept text input when the JavaScript detects that 'go' has been pressed. Credit to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890216/hide-keyboard-in-iphone-safari-webapp

Answer (score 8):

With jQuery

You should unfocus the input from the button you click,

```
$("#button_id_clicked").click(function() {
    $("#search_input_id").blur(); // UNFOCUS THE INPUT                          
});
```

I use it on my web app