# iOS dismiss keyboard programmatically (website, not app)?

Tags: jquery, ios

Currently using this function to dismiss the keyboard on iOS.

The issue is that this doesn't work properly with UI dialogs with forms, and wondering if there's a better approach.

```
var hideKeyboard = function () {
        if ( document.activeElement !== null ) {
            document.activeElement.blur();
            jQ('input').blur();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try focus()ing on a non-text element, like the submit button.

try this [hide keyboard in iphone safari webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890216/hide-keyboard-in-iphone-safari-webapp)

Answer (score 1):

the question is not very clear...
maybe the event you use to trigger the `hideKeyboard` function is also handled by the UI library.
Can you try `event.stopPropogation()` or `event.preventDefault()` when you call `hideKeyboard()`?